# "Five things to do for free" vs "Five free things to do" vs "Free five things to do"

Tags: british-english

I'm having a dilemma writing a slogan for my website.

Website features articles of 5 free items to in specific locations.

Which of the following taglines sounds most professional and British english?

"Five things to do for free" 
"Five free things to do" 
"Free five things to do"

Comment: "Five free things to do in London" is the best way to write this.  it's snappier than "to do for free" and probably better grammar i think.

Comment: "Free five things to do" makes it seem like just the list is free.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ditch the last one; you need to start with the number.

You wouldn't say "I can see black three cats" and the same goes for your sentence.

> Five things to do for free

...fits best with web parlance but be aware that "for free", although very common, is often frowned upon by some grammarists - and you did mention you wanted to go professional.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say it depends on the impact value wanted and the context of the site. Basically - "what are you trying to sell"?

If wanting to promote and emphasise 'free' (*click/link bait* basically) then I would agree with the '`Five things to do for free`'  - if you're more a sophisticated travel guide informing about free things to do in a city, then I'd go with a more sophisticated version.